# Referencing an XML file from XSLT (in a table)

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XML file that looks something like this:

```
<Page>
    <SessionData>
        <Reprice>
            <TotalTax>
                <Amount>100.00</Amount>
            </TotalTax>
```

and then an XSLT file trying to reference said XML file in a table like this;

```
<table>
    <tr bgcolor="#3c78c7">
        <th> </th>
        <th>Cost per Adult</th>
        <th>Cost per Child</th>
        <th>Cost for all passengers</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Page/SessionData/Reprice/TotalTax">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Amount"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

I'm only just starting to learn XML/XSLT so it's probably something tiny and ridiculous. The issue is I'm getting no data in my table :(

Comment: Not sure what your question is.

Comment: Hi sorry, realised after I had posted. The issue is when I open my XSLT in chrome, I don't see any of the data that should be referenced from the XML file

Comment: There is a known issue with using Chrome with local XSLT files - do a search for it. In general, a browser is not a good XSLT testing tool. Get an application that will provide error messages. Or perhaps use http://xsltransform.net/